# How to convert a branched project to a normal project

Tags: tfs

I created a branch of my project in TFS, it helps me to make a copy from project in easiest way, but I want to prevent everyone who works on these copies from merging them.

I was wondering if there is any way to convert this new branched project to normal project and cut all relations between each of new project with others and main project??

Answer (score 0):

If you mean something like the **undo** "Convert to Branch" function.

> Select the branch and then go to **File > Source Control > Branching &
>   Merging > Convert to Folder**.

To prevent everyone who works on these copies from merging them, another way is by [setting TFS branch permission](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/branch-permissions)

Comment: I know that, but it doesn't remove relations between the main project and branched projects and you still can merge them with each others.

Comment: What you described is more like a personal branch. You should consider Git on TFS instead of TFVC  or use Git-tf and have local branches . For now you may have to use some permission settings to block others merging (related permission **Contribute**)or seeing the branch (related permission **Read** )in TFS source control. Details please see my link above